# Pandas dataframe not able to load more than 1048571 rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was using `read_csv` to load a `csv` file into `dataframe` using following command

```
df = pd.read_csv('2016sales data.csv',skiprows = 3)
```

Then, I checked the shape the dataframe

```
df.shape
```

**output:**

```
(1687530, 28)
```

but when i ran this command

```
df.tail(5)
```

Output showed me that there are total 5 rows whose last index was `1048571`. Does this mean that only `1048571` rows were loaded despite of the fact that `df.shape`, shows `1687530` rows.

Comment: Is Excel part of your workflow? `1,048,576` is the maximum number of rows in certain versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but when I work with very big dataframes, setting the kwarg `low_memory=False` on the `read_csv` function saves the day most of the times.